# How do I rerun a jquery script after .load()?

Tags: jquery

Ok, so I have been experimenting with dynamic page loads `.load(page + ' #content')`. It's supposed to change only the `#content` of my page.

However, in one of my pages, services.php, the `#content` has a jquery accordion script. It runs ok if I started from services.php but not if I started from else where.

I hope Im being clear.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out while going through the Jquery documentations that the solution to my problem is `$.getScript('/js/accordion.js');`